# Post request returns the webpage authenticated but webview still shows the login webpage

Tags: react-native, post, webview, http-post, react-native-webview

I'm new in React Native and I'm having an issue with react-native-webview after doing a post request.
On my app, a user logs in with a client number and a password that I store in SQLite because I'll use this data. When a user touches in an option on a SideMenu called "Backoffice", it opens a WebView but before load an URL, it makes a post request to a specific URL with the client number and the password recovered from SQLite. This post request returns an authenticated web page, but  when the webview loads the URL I defined, it fills with the unauthenticated webpage, that's to say, the login webpage.
I do a similar test on a browser and it works ok, the case of the webview doesn't happen.
I still spend a lot of days with this. I'll appreciate any type of help.

Comment: it will be a lot easier to troubleshoot if you can share a piece of the code on how the webview is rendered.

Comment: Sure! I'm using redux.

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
.
.
.
 class BackOfficeForm extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: this.props.url }}
        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
      />
    );
  }
}